# R value reference in function pointer

Tags: c++

I have seen a usage in function pointer:

```
void subMyCallback3(MyCallback&& callback) {
    callback(1);
}
```

I could not see any difference in an example project like the one below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;

using MyCallback = std::function<void(int x)>;

void subMyCallback1(MyCallback callback) {
    printf("%p \n", &callback);
    callback(1);
}


void subMyCallback3(MyCallback&& callback) {
    printf("%p \n", &callback);
    callback(1);
}

int main() {
    auto func = [](int x) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;    
    };
    printf("%p \n", &func);
    subMyCallback1(func);
    subMyCallback3(std::move(func));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x7fff8ade477f 
0x7fff8ade4780 
1
0x7fff8ade4780 
1
```

What's the advantage of using it like this?

Comment: There can be multiple reasons why the original code is written like that. Only analyzing the entire relevant chunk of code will uncover the precise reason why.

Comment: I see no benefit in this case. It seems probable that you constructed this example to simplify the actual case you saw, but in the process you changed something that would make the rvalue reference significant without realizing it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik in original function, it is updating vector and  vector is passed instead of integer.

Comment: I'm afraid that code speaks louder than words, for me. I have no idea what "updating vector" and "vector is passed instead of integer" means, with respect to the shown usage of a callable object.